# How can I install a module on colaboaratory?

Tags: python, kdb, qpython, google-colaboratory

I am testing out Googles colaboratory and I am getting an error

ImportError: No module named qpython

I know because its a virtual machine the modules are installed there but if one is missing is there a way to get it installed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!pip install qpython` is the recommended approach: we can't hope to have every possible dep installed, so users should just install what they need.

Comment: I didn't see how I could install from the browser, thanks!